# What's missing in my local pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I just started learning pyspark and here seems to be a showstopper: I tried to load a local text file into spark:

```py
base_df = sqlContext.read.text("/root/Downloads/SogouQ1.txt")
```

> 16/12/29 11:55:20 INFO text.TextRelation: Listing hdfs://localhost:9000/root/Downloads/SogouQ1.txt on driver

```
base_df.show(10)
```

> 16/12/29 11:55:36 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2 stored
>   as values in memory (estimated size 61.8 KB, free 78.0 KB) 16/12/29
>   11:55:36 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2_piece0 stored as
>   bytes in memory (estimated size 19.6 KB, free 97.6 KB) 16/12/29
>   11:55:36 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in
>   memory on localhost:35556 (size: 19.6 KB, free: 511.1 MB) 16/12/29
>   11:55:36 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 2 from showString
>   at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2 16/12/29 11:55:36 INFO
>   storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_3 stored as values in memory
>   (estimated size 212.1 KB, free 309.7 KB) 16/12/29 11:55:36 INFO
>   storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_3_piece0 stored as bytes in
>   memory (estimated size 19.6 KB, free 329.2 KB) 16/12/29 11:55:36 INFO
>   storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_3_piece0 in memory on
>   localhost:35556 (size: 19.6 KB, free: 511.1 MB) 16/12/29 11:55:36 INFO
>   spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 3 from showString at
>   NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2 Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in    File
>   "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 257, in show
>       print(self._jdf.showString(n, truncate))   File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line
>   813, in **call**   File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line
>   45, in deco
>       return f(*a, **kw)   File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 308,
>   in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred
>   while calling o34.showString. : java.io.IOException: No input paths
>   specified in job  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:201)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:313)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:199)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
>     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
>     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
>     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
>     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:190)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Limit.executeCollect(basicOperators.scala:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollectPublic(SparkPlan.scala:174)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1499)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1499)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withNewExecutionId(DataFrame.scala:2086)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1(DataFrame.scala:1498)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$collect(DataFrame.scala:1505)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$head$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1375)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$head$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1374)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withCallback(DataFrame.scala:2099)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.head(DataFrame.scala:1374)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.take(DataFrame.scala:1456)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.showString(DataFrame.scala:170)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I apologize for the messing error message showing here in StackOverflow, I don't know how to beautify it.

When I do this, it works:

```
wordsDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('cat',), ('elephant',), ('rat',), ('rat',), ('cat',)],['word'])
wordsDF.show()
```

```
+--------+
|    word|
+--------+
|     cat|
|elephant|
|     rat|
|     rat|
|     cat|
+--------+
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @user6910411, the link he provided is the answer to my question:

```
base_df = sqlContext.read.text("file:///root/Downloads/SogouQ1.txt")
```